# Azure Function Identity Providers and Deployment Slots

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I'm using an openid connect identity provider with an azure function. I'm looking to add a deployment slot for dev, with the current endpoint being used for production. Dev and production will obviously have two separate endpoints. The identity provider requires a callback url to redirect the user back to after deploying. However, in the portal, the identity providers seem to be for the whole azure function and not per deployment slot. Can we not use openid connect identity providers when using deployment slots?

Comment: IMO, slots are a little old and you're better off having an entirely new resource group with a function app for dev that has it's own identity.  Through the use of DevOps, you can then deploy accordingly via your branches.  It's just my opinion but a fairly common approach these days.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a UI issue. If you go into "deployment slots" and select a different slot, when you click the config tab, the settings apply to that tab. Same for auth. It's just not very clear from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin) this is can be created using Devops by creating branches rather than creating Identity providers and deployment slots the below dev document can be helpful in understanding how to create branches.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser